# Skipping the first line when reading in a file in 1.9.3

Tags: ruby, rake-task, ruby-1.9.3

I'm using ruby's File to open and read in a text file inside of a rake 
task. Is there a setting where I can specify that I want the first line of 
the file skipped? 
Here's my code so far:

```
desc "Import users." 
  task :import_users => :environment do 
    File.open("users.txt", "r", '\r').each do |line| 
      id, name, age, email = line.strip.split(',') 
      u = User.new(:id => id, :name => name, :age => age, :email => email) 
      u.save 
    end 
  end
```

I tried `line.lineno` and also doing `File.open("users.txt", "r", '\r').each do |line, index|` and `next if index == 0` but have not had any luck.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Change `each` to `each_with_index do |line, index|` and `next if index == 0` will work.

Answer (score 24):

function `drop(n)` will remove `n` lines from the beginning:

```rb
File.readlines(filename).drop(1).each do |line| 
  puts line
end
```

It will read the whole file into an array and remove first `n` lines. If you are reading whole file anyway it's probably the most elegant solution.

When reading larger files `foreach` will be more efficient, as it doesn't read all data into memory:

```
File.foreach(filename).with_index do |line, line_num|
  next if line_num == 0
  puts line
end
```

Comment: you mean File.readlines("users.txt").drop(1).each do |line| , your example gives an error

Answer (score 9):

```
File.open("users.txt", "r", '\r') do |file|
  lines = file.lines # an enumerator
  lines.next #skips first line
  lines.each do |line|
    puts line # do work
  end
end
```

Making use of an enumerator, which 'remembers' where it is.

Answer (score 4):

You probably really want to use csv:

```
CSV.foreach("users.txt", :headers, :header_converters => :symbol, :col_sep => ',') do |row|
  User.new(row).save
end
```

Answer (score 4):

```
File.readlines('users.txt')[1..-1].join()
```

Works good too.

Comment: `File.readlines('users.txt').drop(1).join` is even a little bit simpler :)

Answer (score 2):

if you want to keep the file as IO the whole time (no array conversions) and you plan on using the data in the first line:

```
f = File.open('users.txt', 'r')
first_line = f.gets
body = f.readlines
```

More likely though, what you want is handled by CSV or FasterCSV as others have pointed out.  My favorite way to handle files with a header line is to do:

```
FasterCSV.table('users.txt')
```

Answer (score 1):

Since a few answers (no longer ?) work in Ruby 1.9.3, here a working sample of the three best methods

```
# this line must be dropped
puts "using drop"
File.readlines(__FILE__).drop(1).each do |line| 
  puts line
end 
puts ""

puts "using a range"
File.readlines(__FILE__)[1..-1].each do |line| 
  puts line
end
puts ""

puts "using enumerator"
File.readlines(__FILE__).each do |file, w|
    lines = file.lines # an enumerator
    lines.next #skips first line
    lines.each do |line|
        puts line
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The OP said `lineno` didn't work for them, but I'm guessing it wasn't applied in the correct way. There's lots of ways achieve what the OP is asking for, but using `lineno` might help you shorten up your code without having to use `readlines`, which is sometimes too memory intensive.

From the [1.9.3 docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-i-each_line)

```
f = File.new("testfile")
f.each {|line| puts "#{f.lineno}: #{line}" }
```

produces:

```
1: This is line one
2: This is line two
3: This is line three
4: And so on...
```

Note that is a method you can call from the file object, but not the object yielded to the block.

```
   2:     require 'pry'; binding.pry
=> 3:   f.each {|line| puts line.lineno }

[1] pry(#<SomeFile>)> line.lineno
NoMethodError: undefined method `lineno' for #<String:0x00007fa7d682b920>
```

You can find the same [example](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/IO.html#method-i-each_line) with identical code in docs for the latest stable version of Ruby today (2.5.1).

So going off the example, the code might look like

```
f = File.new("testfile")
o = File.open("output.txt", w)
f.each do |line|
  next if f.lineno == 1
  o << line
end
```